# Changing length of the_content in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm building a site for a client that requires different lengths for just about everything.  `the_excerpt` tag is already being shortened to 15 words, but I need `the_content()` to be shortened on the main "updates" page, but then need to work to its full form (unlimited) on the actual post page.

How would I go about doing this?  Does anyone know if there's a way to alter `the_content` output PER page?

How could I create a 'function' that basically does the following

`the_content("short")` for the blogs landing page, 
`the_content();` normal output works normally on single.php?

Answer (score 1):

put the following code into your theme `functions.php`

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

instead of 20 use your desired excerpt length you want

Answer (score 0):

You can change the character length of `the_excerpt()` by putting the following code in your `functions.php`:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length');
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions: 
First solution : Apply filter to the filter hook `the_content`, like this  :
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_function_name' ) 
(placed in functions.php). Then create the function `filter_function_name` to find the context of the call and conditionnaly shorten the length of the return. See here for more info on applying filters to the_content : http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

Second solution : 
do not use the_content() but your own function like sp_content().

```
function sp_content($length) {
    if ($length == "") { $content = get_the_content();  }
    else { $content = substr(get_the_content(), 0, $length) }
    return $content;
}
```

Or even easier : when you need the long content, use `the_content()` and in any other case, just use `short_content()` after creating your own function like this :

```
short_content() {
    substr(get_the_content())... etc.
}
```